# Return to current Album in iTunes on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, itunes, mac

I select album and now I am listening it. But I am lookking the other music in iTunes. So I now I have the one album I am listening now and other page in my iTunes, like this:

[image]

What do I need to do to quickly return to my current played album page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press CMD+L.

Enjoy your music!

Edit:
You may also go to

Controls > Go to Current Song